# Best chatting framework for a flutter-node.js pair?

Tags: node.js, flutter, chat

I am working on a flutter app with a node.js backend. I need to implement a real time chat service and also intend to store the chat data in mongodb database.The number of options I have considered are :

- Websockets
- Long polling
- Third party services like pusher or pubnub(Both does n't have sdk for flutter 
  so any advice would be appreciated)
- Firebase (Easy to implement with flutter but I am confused how should I store data on mongodb then ? Api rquest for every message ?)

I need a quick solution for the initial phase of the application but also need to think whether I can extend it later(With increase in users)

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score -1):

Ankit, we're working on a flutter SDK at Ably, however it's not ready for prime time. [Get in touch with the team](https://www.ably.io/contact) if you're serious about this requirement as it's possible this work can be accelerated forwards.

Otherwise, check the list of [Ably Realtime SDKs](https://www.ably.io/download) in a few months as you may find we have a Flutter SDK by then.

Good luck with your service.